# While installing yolov3 using conda on window10 getting error Solving environment: failed

Tags: python, conda, yolo

When I am trying to install `yolov3` on `windows10` using `Conda`, getting following error:

```
(base) D:\aaa\yolo>conda env create -f yolo.yml
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed  ResolvePackageNotFound:   
vc==14.1=h0510ff6_3  
vs2015_runtime==15.5.2=3
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: anyone please help i need it for project

Comment: Could you say what you need?

Comment: Edit your question to include which `yolov3` package/repo you're using, contents of `yolo.yml ` and Conda version